# What's the most efficient way to divide a table by a threshold into two sub-queries in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table *test* with schema `id`(int) and `height`(numeric) in PostgreSQL.

I need to divide them by a certain height then calculate each sub-query.

```sql
with above as (
  select id, height
  from test
  where height >= 1
)
below as (
  select id, height
  from test
  where height < 1
)
-- do something with each sub-query
```

To my understanding the two sub-query above will iterate the table twice.

In a programming language such as python, i can put data in a *list* then just iterate through the list 1 time by removing and storing `> 1` items found in the set to another list, then the remaining list will be the result of "below"

Is there an equivalent way to do this in SQL (To be specific, PostgreSQL)?

Comment: There are set operators such as `EXCEPT`. But it would be more interesting what "do something with each sub-query" really is as there might be some possibilities like conditional aggregation. It also depends in that and the rest of the schema (i.e. indexes)  what really gets "iterated".

Comment: Each entity is a list of 3d geometry point. I'm trying to split the geometry into two part that one is above the given z value, and the other half below the z value. Then make concave hull for each set of points. Thought it was too complicated to the problem. The points are not spatial indexed as they are dumped from a geometry.

Comment: @eth4io . . . You seem to be trying to optimize something that may not need to be optimized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sql you can do it by flagging the two groups with one iteration:

```
  select id, height , case when height >= 1 then 'above' else 'below' end as heightFlag
  from test
```

If you want you can create a new table in sql, p iterate through the original 1 time by removing and storing > 1 items found in the set the new table